# Input/Output Issue with simple program.

Tags: c++, input

I have a homework assignment I'm having a bit of trouble with. I seem to have no errors, but when I run the program and input text....nothing happens.

For example, to test it I usually put in "Robertson, Bob John" and hit enter. Can anyone help me with this?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string> 

using namespace std;

int main () {

//Title and instructions
cout << "This program will output your name in first-to-last order!" << endl;
cout << "Please type your name in the following manner: last, first middle."; << endl;

//Declare the strings being used
string firstName;
string middleName;
string lastName;

//Put user input into strings, ignore the comma
cin >> lastName >> firstName >> middleName >> endl;
cin.ignore(',');

//Output the name in first-to-last order
cout << "Your name is: " << first <<' '<< middle <<' '<< last << endl;

//Pause before exiting
return 0;

}
```

Comment: This code does not compile. If you want our help, show us the real code.

Comment: `//Pause before exiting  return 0;` - this is not a pause, but [return code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exit_status).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you have a couple of compilation errors; an extra semicolon on your second `cout`, wrong variable names when you're trying to `cout` your output, etc. But the real problem is your `cin.ignore(',');`. It seems to be hanging for some reason. I'm going to guess, based on [the cin documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/ignore/), that it's interpreting the comma as a number, and it will ignore that many characters.

You'll need to remove the comma yourself after the `cin`; I've left that as an exercise for you.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main () {

//Title and instructions
cout << "This program will output your name in first-to-last order!" << endl;
cout << "Please type your name in the following manner: last, first middle." << endl;

//Declare the strings being used
string firstName;
string middleName;
string lastName;

//Put user input into strings, ignore the comma
cin >> lastName >> firstName >> middleName;

//Output the name in first-to-last order
cout << "Your name is: " << firstName <<' '<< middleName <<' '<< lastName << endl;

//Pause before exiting
return 0;

}
```

Comment: Ah, I copied some older code by accident. Thank you for the answer, helped me a lot. Literally my third assignment haha.

Comment: @user3345181 No problem. We've all got to start somewhere! ^_^ Don't forget to accept my answer by checking the little checkmark next to it, that will give us both some reputation.

Comment: @user3345181 Also, here are a few sites you can learn from and look things up on. They should help you along your journey. [cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/) and [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp)

Answer (score 1):

Since you say it compiles, presumably your real code doesn't have a rogue `;` in the second `cout` line, doesn't try to read into `endl`, and uses the correct variable names in the final `cout`.

Assuming there are no other differences, the problem is this:

```
cin.ignore(',');
```

I'm not sure what you want that to do; but it waits until you enter an extra 44 characters (interpreting ',' as its ASCII value 44) after the name before proceeding.

If you want to ignore the comma after the last name, it's probably easiest to read it with the comma, then remove it with `lastName.pop_back()` (perhaps checking that there really is a comma there first).

By the way, my father has no middle name, and my sister has two. Are they not allowed to use your program?